# can we deploy whole project in Google Cloud using only Code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a project in Google cloud using the following resources

-BigQuery, Google functions (Python), google storage, Cloud Scheduler

is it possible to save the whole project as code and share it, so someone else can just use that code and deploy it using his own tenant ?

the reason, I am asking, I have published all the code and SQL queries in Github, but some users find it very hard to reproduce, they are not necessarily very familiar with Google Cloud, in an ideal situation, they need just to get a file and click deploy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a solution for GCP we will commonly find that it consists of code, data and configuration.  The code and data you can save in a source repository like GitHub ... but what of the configuration?  What if your "solution" expects to have BQ datasets and tables or GCS buckets or Scheduler jobs defined?  This is where you can create "Infrastructure As Code" definitions.  Google supports its own IaC technology called [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/) but you can also use the popular Terraform as it too has a GCP provider.  The definitions for these IaC coordinators are typically text / yaml files that you can also package with your code.  Sprinkle in some Make, Chef, Puppet for building apps and pushing code to deployment environments and you have a "build it from source" story.  Study also the concepts of CI/CD and you will commonly find that the steps you perform for building CI/CD overlap with the steps for trivial deployment.

There are also projects such as [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) that can do some kind of a job of reverse engineering an existing configuration to create IaC description that, when run elsewhere, will recreate the configuration.